# AWS ECS RunTask overrides for memory and cpu are not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, boto3, aws-ecs

I'm trying to override the CPU and memory limits on a container when using the [RunTask](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_RunTask.html) command. I'm using the Python SDK, boto3.

The container has default CPU limit of 0 (unlimited) and a soft memory limit of 1024. That's all fine and good.

When I attempt to pass a `containerOverrides` list to the RunTask command, I don't get an error, the tasks runs mostly as expected. I'm also overriding the command the container runs, and that works - I can see as the task is running the command has been overridden, and the logs reflect this.

**The CPU and memory limits, however, are not being overridden.** I'm checking this by peeking at the AWS console and seeing the cpu and memory are listed as 0 and 1024, but the command is shown to be overridden. I can also do a little math by checking on the container instance to confirm the memory is not the desired 2048, but must be 1024.

Here's some simplified code:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ecs')

overrides = {
        "containerOverrides": [
        {
            "name": "runcommand",
            "command": command_wrapper,
            "cpu": 512,
            "memory": 2048,
            "memoryReservation": 2048
        }
        ]
    }

response = client.run_task(
        cluster='mycluster',
        taskDefinition='runcommand-qa',
        overrides=overrides,
        group='stackoverflow:run-command'
    )
```

And the `tasks` section of the response:

```
'tasks': [{
    'taskArn': 'arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:12345667890:task/72f1a8ae-4f51-4717-acc6-fce3199a9e92',
    'group': 'stackoverflow:run-command',
    'attachments': [],
    'overrides': {
        'containerOverrides': [{
            'memoryReservation': 2048,
            'memory': 2048,
            'command': ['sh', '-c', '. /app/bin/activate && ./manage.py help'],
            'name': 'runcommand',
            'cpu': 512
        }]
    },
    'launchType': 'EC2',
    'lastStatus': 'PENDING',
    'containerInstanceArn': 'arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:12345667890:container-instance/f0dd320e-b1de-413d-8e1c-c64b0799e473',
    'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 25, 9, 4, 3, 46000, tzinfo = tzlocal()),
    'version': 1,
    'clusterArn': 'arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:12345667890:cluster/runcommand-qa',
    'memory': '2048',
    'desiredStatus': 'RUNNING',
    'taskDefinitionArn': 'arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:12345667890:task-definition/runcommand-qa:127',
    'cpu': '512',
    'containers': [{
        'containerArn': 'arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:12345667890:container/80949a81-747f-4729-a9d4-922007448729',
        'taskArn': 'arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:12345667890:task/72f1a8ae-4f51-4717-acc6-fce3199a9e92',
        'lastStatus': 'PENDING',
        'name': 'runcommand',
        'networkInterfaces': []
    }]
}]
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

cpu and memory needs to be defined in the Task Overrides, not just containerOverrides.
like this

```
overrides = {
        "cpu": "512",
        "memory": "2048",
        "containerOverrides": [
          {
            "name": "runcommand",
            "command": command_wrapper,
            "cpu": 512,
            "memory": 2048,
          }
         ]
    }
```

notice that inside containerOverrides they are defined as `int`, as task overrides they need to be defined as `str`.
this worked for me on FARGATE ecs tasks, with boto3 version 1.15.16

Comment: This solution works correctly. boto3 documentation is not clear in this regard